# Problema no agendamento para envio de avisos por e-mail Spring e JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Bom dia,

Estou usando o spring com o Scheduled, antes usava o quartz mas como fiz upload da versão do spring resolvi abandonar o quartz ja que a primeira opção era o suficiente para atender minha necessidade.

Resumindo, tenho uma tarefa que envia e-mails, esse abaixo é o evento.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class NotificacaoScheduler {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoService notificacao;
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)//1800000
    public void scheduleFixedRateTask() {
        notificacao.analisar();
        logger.debug("Fixed rate task - " + LocalDateTime.now());
        notificacao.enviarPendentes();
        logger.debug("Send ok - " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Abaixo o service,

```
@Service
public class NotificacaoService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired 
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Autowired
    private Notificacoes notificacao;
    @Autowired
    private NotificacoesEnvios envios;
    @Transactional
    public void analisar() {
        List<Notificacao> result = notificacao.buscarHoje();
        List<NotificacaoEnvio> notEnvios = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Notificacao n : result) {
            if(!notificacao.verSeExiste(n)) {
                NotificacaoEnvio ne = new NotificacaoEnvio();
                ne.setNotificacao(n);
                ne.setStatus(false);
                notEnvios.add(ne);
            }
        }
        if(!notEnvios.isEmpty()) envios.saveAll(notEnvios);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void enviarPendentes() {
        List<NotificacaoEnvio> ne = notificacao.notificacoesPendentes();
        List<NotificacaoEnvio> nList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (NotificacaoEnvio n : ne) {
            try {
                MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail);
                helper.setTo(n.getNotificacao().getPara().replace(" ", "").split(";"));
                if(!n.getNotificacao().getCc().trim().equals(""))
                    helper.setCc(n.getNotificacao().getCc().replace(" ", "").split(";"));
                if(!n.getNotificacao().getCo().trim().equals(""))
                    helper.setBcc(n.getNotificacao().getCo().replace(" ", "").split(";"));
                helper.setSubject(n.getNotificacao().getAssunto());
                helper.setText(n.getNotificacao().getModelo().getTexto(),true);
                helper.setFrom(n.getNotificacao().getDe(),n.getNotificacao().getAutor());
                mailSender.send(mail);
                n.setDataEnvio(Calendar.getInstance());
                n.setStatus(true);
                nList.add(n);
            } catch (NullPointerException | MailException | MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(!nList.isEmpty()) envios.saveAll(nList);
    }
}
```

O que ocorre, que tenho notifição que é gerada em uma tabela de pendencias, que a cada 1 hora é enviado as notificações pendentes, o problema esta justamente ai, o metodo analisar() esta funcionando corretamente, porem o metodo enviarPendentes(), esta enviando a mesma notificação 2 vezes (não existe duas linhas do mesmo registro no meu banco). Durante os testes que fiz no eclipse, apenas uma vez era enviado, mas lá no servidor tomcat estou com esse problema.

Abaixo o metodo de consulta a base

```
@Override
public List<NotificacaoEnvio> notificacoesPendentes(){
    Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(NotificacaoEnvio.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("data", Calendar.getInstance()));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", false));
     return criteria.list();
}
```

Abraços e Feliz Ano novo a todos

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente seu problema está em múltiplas instâncias do seu `Scheduler` sendo executadas ao mesmo tempo.

Algumas considerações:

1. Se você configurar sua aplicação por meio de XML e annotations, pode ser que uma instância seja criada através das annotations e consequentemente uma nova instância criada após o XML ser considerado pelo contexto, [como discutido no bug SPR-10830](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10830)
2. Seu contexto de aplicação está sendo carregado duas vezes
3. Deploy duplicado no servidor

De qualquer forma, tente também executar seu `Scheduler` fora da classe de configuração, por exemplo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class JobSchedulerConfig {}
```

A annotation `@EnableScheduling` faz o seguinte:

> This enables detection of @Scheduled annotations on any Spring-managed bean in the container.

Desta forma você pode ter suas configurações de jobs fora da classe de configuração.

E seu job de notificação:

```
@Component
public class NotificacaoJob {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoService notificacao;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
    public void doSchedule() {
        notificacao.analisar();
        logger.debug("Fixed rate task - " + LocalDateTime.now());
        notificacao.enviarPendentes();
        logger.debug("Send ok - " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }

}
```

Caso seu job não for localizado, você pode incluir a annotation `@ComponentScan(basePackages="meu.pacote.scheduler")` para indicar o Spring onde encontrá-los.

A referência relacionada à configuração do job pode ser encontrada na [documentação do Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html), alguns dos pontos que mencionei podem ser encontrados também [nesta thread do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242310/java-spring-scheduled-tasks-executing-twice)

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, vou tentar o metodo que me sugeriu, so pra constar configurei apenas por annotations. So não entendo porque é executado duas vezes. Mesmo assim vou testar no projeto e dou um retorno. Muito obrigado

Comment: tentei fazer como mencionado, mas não deu certo, ainda continua enviando 2 vezes. se não der certo vou usar o quartz

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, enfim consegui resolver, não entendi o problema, mas trocando a anotação @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000) por cron já não deu mais problema.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class NotificacaoJob{
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoService notificacao;
    @Autowired 
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * * *")
    public void execute() {
    //restante do codigo aqui
    }
}
```